# Problem with luamesh in MikTeX

Tags: luatex, miktex

After trying to test [`Amurmaple`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerthemeamurmaple) beamer theme and [`luamesh`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamesh) package on my MikTeX system, both finished with the same error:

```
(C:/Users/UIB/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/
libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))...ppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/scripts
/luamesh/luamesh.lua:7: module 'luamesh-polygon' not found:
    no field package.preload['luamesh-polygon']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luamesh-polygon'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luamesh-polygon'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...ppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/scripts/luamesh/luamesh.lua:7: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.14 \directlua{require("luamesh.lua")}
```

As I'm not used to `LuaLaTeX` so I don't know what it means and don't find information about it. `Luamesh` installation was done by MikTeX itself so I presume that the installation is correct.

Could you help me?

I simple file to test is could be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamesh}

\begin{document}

  \meshPolygon[
  tikz,
  color = blue!70,
  %meshpoint = \alpha,
  colorPolygon=black,
  scale=4cm,
  step=mesh,
 % print=points,
  gridpoints=perturb
  ]
  {(0,0);(1,0);(1,1);(0,1)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the same message with miktex. Works with texlive. Perhaps worth reporting at [miktex-packaging](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging)?

Comment: Looks like miktex misplaces luamesh-polygon.lua and luamesh-tex.lua in `.../MiKTeX/source` rather than `.../MiKTeX/scripts`. I'll report to miktex

Comment: Will be fixed tomorrow, see [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/321)